# Shell if else nested loop error

Tags: shell, loops, if-statement, scripting, nested

This is my script ...i get this error below. I suspect second if else is wrong but unble to figure that out ..

```
read -p "Do you wish to continue the merge session? (y/n) " RESP
if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
    co_repo=`echo $target_url | cut -d "/" -f 7`
    co_workspace="svn_promote_$co_repo"
    echo "$co_workspace ................................................."
    if [-d "$co_workspace" ] then;
        echo -e "Creating target workspace $co_workspace"
        echo -e ""
        mkdir $co_workspace
        echo -e "Checking out $target_url .."
        svn co $target_url $co_workspace
    else
        echo -e "Target workspace exists. Updating ..."
        svn update $co_workspace
    fi
else
    echo "Exiting promote session .."
fi
```

Error:

```
monday_try.sh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
monday_try.sh: line 44: `                    else'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolon goes *before* `then`, not after it.

Answer (score 1):

What @Wumpus says, plus

```
if [-d "$co_workspace" ]
```

needs a space after the `[`:

```
if [ -d "$co_workspace" ]
```

Comment: @iaav, remember `[` is a *command*, helps to remember it needs to be surrounded by spaces